# How to import a sub-component in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I create a custom vue.js component.

Component scratch : /scratch/index.js :

```
import drawArea from './drawArea.vue';
import scratchList from './scratchList.vue';

export default  {
    drawArea,
    scratchList,
}
```

In main.vue

```
  <template>
    <drawArea></drawArea>
  </template>
  <script > 
  import {drawArea, scratchList} from '../components/Scratcher';
  export default {
    components: {
      'drawArea': drawArea, 
   },
  }
  </script>
```

But I get an error:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

How can I correctly register my component?

Thank you.

Comment: It's scratch or Scratcher? Fix it.

Comment: Try `<draw-area></draw-area>`. And do check the import `from '../components/Scratcher';` as mentioned above. Is it correct?